# GitHub API, fetch commits as local files

Tags: github, github-api

I am newbie to GitHub API, and I have been looking for an automated way  that I can download all commits of a specific repository in GitHub as “local files”  into my machine but without success.

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "local files"? Also, what language are you hoping to do this in?

Comment: I meant that "local files" to store the commits in my machine as "file.cpp" for instance.  I am doing this using shell script.

Comment: If you clone the repo, then part of that process brings down all of the commits to your 'local files'. The api returns JSON objects. Still not sure what you are trying to do, why, or what language you are trying to accomplish this in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

- simply git clone the GitHub repo: you will get the files checked out by the default branch, and all the commits in the .git subfolder
- Or [get the archive link of a repo](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link) and then curl said archive (but you will get only the repo content, not "all the commits"
- Or [list the commits on a repo](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository), using the `?path=a/file/path` argument to filter said commits and only get the ones for a given `file.cpp`

Comment: I see that all the commits being fetched with cloning the repos. It seems that using ?path=a/file/path retrieve the url of a commit not the raw file. I could use diff tool within .git directory but not sure if I could store the whole committed file as raw file.

Comment: @Hex true, the `?path=/a/file/path` would list the files inside a commit, but that does include its `raw_url` field.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to [list the commits](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository) on a repo via Github API, you can use the following bash script that will iterate over all the commits and write them to a single file in a root JSON Array.

You can add your own [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) filters if you want select specific fields or filter anything else :

```
#!/bin/bash

# change those vars :
GITHUB_USER=google
GITHUB_REPO=gson
OUTPUT_FILE=commit_list.json
GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN=1234567890123445678

loop=0
index=1
TMP_FILE=tmpfile.txt
PER_PAGE=100


rm -f $TMP_FILE
echo "[]" > $OUTPUT_FILE

while [ "$loop" -ne 1 ]
do
    URI="https://api.github.com/repos/$GITHUB_USER/$GITHUB_REPO/commits?page=$index&per_page=$PER_PAGE&access_token=$GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN"
    data=`curl -s $URI`

    # add some filter here if needed (for instance `echo "$data" | jq '[ .[].commit ]`)
    filtered=`echo "$data"`

    check=`echo "$filtered" | jq 'if (type=="array" and length>0) then "continue" else "stop" end'`

    if [ "$check" == '"stop"' ]; then
        loop=1
    else
        echo "$filtered" > $TMP_FILE
        concat=`jq -s add $TMP_FILE $OUTPUT_FILE`
        echo "$concat" > $OUTPUT_FILE
        size=`jq '. | length' $OUTPUT_FILE`
        echo "computed $index page - fetched total commit count of : $size"
        index=$((index+1))
    fi
done
```

This script needs [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) and [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/)

The output is located in output file `commit_list.json` which is an array of all [commit JSON object](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository):

```
# jq 'length' commit_list.json
1329
```